# Excel Add-In Context Menu Buttons

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Add-In that I have created ( .xlam file )  I am trying to have this add-in create buttons on the right click menu so that I can quickly run a macro based on the selected cell.  I added code to ThisWorkbook, and it works in the xlsm file.  (I copied the code from [HERE](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4375-excel-add-button-macro-to-right-click-menu.html).)  I SaveAs to an xlam, load the add-in, and I get nothing on the context menu.  I have a feeling these subs do not load through the add-in.  However, I can get code in Workbook_Open to function. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    On Error Resume Next
    With Application
        .CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Open Drawing").Delete
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim cmdBtn As CommandBarButton
    On Error Resume Next

    With Application
        .CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Open Drawing").Delete
        Set cmdBtn = .CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)
    End With

    With cmdBtn
       .Caption = "Open Drawing"
       .Style = msoButtonCaption
       .OnAction = "Open_Drawing_Main"
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `AddinInstall` event. I assume that your context menu procedure works fine. So double click on ThisWorkbook in the add-in file (before you install it and save it as xlam), select `AddinInstall` event from the upper write dropdown menu and place some code like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AddinInstall()
    Call AddToRightClickMenuOptions_Main
End Sub
```

in this code `AddToRightClickMenuOptions_Main` is the sub that creates the context menu. Note that you may want to remove the context menu when you uninstall the add-in:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AddinUninstall()
    Call DeleteFromRightClickMenuOptions_Main
End Sub
```

where `DeleteFromRightClickMenuOptions_Main` is the routine that removes the context menu (you can find the code easily on the internet)

Comment: Q: Will `Workbook_AddinInstall()` run in the non-addin workbook when an addin is installed, or in the addin itself? I always assumed this would trigger in the workbook for which an add-in was being installed.

Comment: A: yes, the context menus work with the right click on a sheet. Once an add-in is installed the user does not see its worksheet and the active worksheets are the ones that provide the functionality

Answer (score 1):

An Excel Add-in (at least, the ones I have created) still have their own workbook. The `Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick` and `Workbook_Deactivate` will run when the **.xlam**'s workbook is either right-clicked or deactivated. If you want the code to run only for when the selected workbook is right-clicked or deactivated, you'll have to have the code in that specific workbook's code.

---

**However**

---

Since you are trying to get this to work with an add-in, I'm going to go through a few relevant points since once an Add-in is loaded, it (and it's features) are accessible from **all** other open workbooks.

- If the option is added to the context menu whenever a page is right-clicked in any book (which it *would* (as coded, if it worked)), removing the context menu option when any workbook is deactivated won't have any visible effect, as the next time a right-click happens the option will once again be visible.
- Is there a reason why the context menu can't just be added when the add-in is opened (add-in's `Workbook_Open`), and removed when it's closed(add-in's `Workbook_BeforeClose`)? (As this will *visibly* have the same effect as the above code.)